# My input text is not saving but return to the original value in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read input from an input field and click a button to store that text, I also want to reset the input field for next input. However, as the input field get restored, the saved data is changed with the input field again! Can anyone please help me with this?
public InputField input;
public Button confirm;

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    confirm.onClick.AddListener(readchartLabelInputOnClick);
    Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("chartLabel"));
}
public void readchartLabelInputOnClick()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("chartLabel", input.text);
    input.text = "Enter Text...";
}
```

This is my debug screenshot:[image]
Looks like the addListener called the function a lot of times. How should I change that?

Comment: You Are adding the callback to OnClick **Every Frame**! Do it only **once** in `Awake` or `Start` ...

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add `confirm.onClick.AddListener(readchartLabelInputOnClick)` inside `Start()` or `Awake()` instead of `Update()`, because in your program's modern state, it adds Listener for the event `Click` every frame, so when your click the button it starts a lot of `readchartLabelInputOnClick()`. It is the reason behind

> Looks like the addListener called the function a lot of times.

2. For the same reason after your input text is written and send in "chartLabel" by the first `readchartLabelInputOnClick()` it is instantly overwritten by new instance of `readchartLabelInputOnClick()`, where `input.text` is now "Enter Text..."

Comment: Thanks man, I solved it now, really appreacited

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative solution.

I would first put a method in the button in the scene (in `OnClick()`) to avoid calling `Update()`, of course the method would also be inside the script, where, when started, it fetches the text with `input.text` and then delete it with `input.text = ""`
If you put a `placeholder` in the `inputfield` in the scene you don't even need to enter "Enter text ..." from the script, and also you won't have to delete it every time to insert the text.

Comment: Thank you!  I solved the problem now, really appreaciated!